# Android Studio fail to open project

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I am using the last version until now 1.2 of Android Studio on mac, and I am trying to start new project. The projet folder and files are created I can see that in the workspace, but the IDE keep the charging state to the infinity like the image below shows.
[image]

I tried to uninstall Android Studio with the commands below and then reinstall it but I still have the same problem
 rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*

rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.studio.plist

rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*

rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*

rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
Does anyone encountered such problem?
 Thank you.

Comment: How long do you define "infinity"? It usually takes a while the first time you start a new project.

Comment: **rm -Rfv ~/.gradle/** use this command too remove gradle files as well and then try too install it back again .

Comment: Try creating a new test account on your mac and install Java JDK / Android Studio / Android SDK - if this is successfully working you can narrow down whether its something to do with your login account, or globally to the system.

Comment: rm -Rfv ~/.gradle/ did the job. After the new installation and in first opening the IDE he asked me to re-set the sdk path and other configuration. So now problem resolved. thank you Brendom !